# python advanced search library

Tags: python, full-text-search

I have around 80,000 text files and I want to be able to do an advanced search on them.
Let's say I have two lists of keywords and I want to return all the files that include at least one of the keywords in the first list and at least one in the second list. 
Is there already a library that would do that, I don't want to rewrite it if it exists.

Comment: Is this one-shot or will you need to do it multiple times, and if multiple times, will the search query, text files, or both be different?

Comment: I would need to do it multiple times, for different lists for the same files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you need to search the documents multiple times, you most likely want to index the text files to makes such searches as fast as possible.

Implementing a reasonable index yourself is certainly possible, but a quick search lead me to:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/
- http://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/

Take a look at the documentation. It should hopefully be rather trivial to achieve the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I just get a feeling you want to use MapReduce type of processing for the search. It should be very scalable, Python should have MapReduce packages.